# What parts of code to include in log?

Tags: logging, server, crash-reports

I am developing a commercial application and I have come to a point
where it's time to wrap it up and deploy.

I know that it is inevitable that my software will crash at one point
or another and I am wondering:

What parts of my code should I log to the crash-report?

Are there any general rules and guidelines that I can read about somewhere?

Should one just log critical sections or log the start/end of each method?

I should also note that my software might run for an extended period
of time since it is running on a server so the log file can become
very large in size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, try to look for critical sections which have a higher probability to break and insert some log.

> I should also note that my software might run for an extended period of time since it is running on a server so the log file can become very large in size.

simply limit your log file to a certain size/lines and each time you exceed this limit just create another one.

Comment: Is it normal or a good idea to also give the log file a life-time? For example keeping the log for X days? and any log that is older than X days will be removed?

Comment: You can do anything that serves your needs, if you think that older files are not important then it's a good idea.